# No wireless connections

Tags: wireless, networking

First of all, I am a complete newbie to Ubuntu, and barely know anything about it, so a lot of detail would be lovely.

Whenever I open the network list it shows one Wired Connection, which I do not use, but no wireless. Do I have to manually add in the information from the "Add" button, or is there a way I can make it do a sort of scan for networks in the general area?

The wireless connection will connect on my Windows OS, which I am on now, but not on Ubuntu. All help is appreciated!

```
ifconfig result:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:db:55:84:dc:73  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:228 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:19306 (19.3 KB)  TX bytes:19306 (19.3 KB)
```

---

```
iwconfig result:

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: try the commands "ifconfig" and "iwconfig", what does it say?

Comment: ifconfig and iwconfig results posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar issue and resolved now. 
i cannot comment to your question so trying to resolve issue via this answer.

Let me know few things

- ubuntu version
- kernel version (uname -a)
- wifi devide is USB or PCI ?
- brand, name and version details of wifi driver.

i will try to update answer with further details.